# Visual editing XAML-files in Xamarin projects. Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2012, xamarin, designer

I have in my Xamarin project several xaml-files. But I can't use visual editing (designer) in Visual Studio 2012 for this files.
Also available Intellisense in the editor xaml-code.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Example error:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

XAML files are not supported by Xamarin Studio and are used by Windows Presentation Foundation projects in Visual Studio.

If you are writing an Android application, I think you want `.axml` files (notice the `a` before `x`), that is a file designing a layout for Android in XML format.
Xamarin Studio is able to edit axml files.